# SQL Query to Set a Value to Itself Plus Value of Another Field

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update

I have a table of customers, with `customerid` as the `PK` and a `currentordertotal` field. I want to combine the `currentordertotal` for two customer records.

For example:

```
Customer C1, Current Order Total = 2

Customer C2, Current Order Total = 4
```

I would like to update `C1’s Current Order Total` to be itself (2) plus `C2’s Current Order Total` (so 6).

So something like:

```
UPDATE customers SET currentordertotal = (itself + currentordertotal  WHERE customerid = C2) WHERE customerid = C1;
```

I have searched online for a similar query but cannot find one.

It's an Oracle DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery is the right approach, but we want to be careful:

```
update customers
    set currentordertotal = (coalesce(currentordertotal, 0) +
                             coalesce((select c2.currentordertotal
                                       from customers c2
                                       where c2.customerid = 'C2'
                                      ), 0)
                            )
    where customerid = 'C1';
```

The coalesce is in case the second customer is missing or the value is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a subquery

```
UPDATE customers SET currentordertotal = currentordertotal  + (select currentordertotal from customers WHERE customerid = C2) WHERE customerid = C1
```